# Delete all files and folders via Ant FTP task

Tags: ant, ftp

How to delete all files and folders inside specified remote folder in Ant?

I've tried the following:

```
<ftp server="${ftp.host}" userid="${ftp.user}"
             password="${ftp.pass}" remotedir="${ftp.remotedir}" action="del">
    <fileset>
        <include name="**/*"/>
    </fileset>
</ftp>
```

it deletes all files, but not folders.
(if I write here <include name="*.txt"> instead it works as expected - deletes all txt files, but what if I want to delete all files and folders?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use another command: `rmdir`. 
This command does not remove folder specified in the `remotedir` parameter.
The sample based on information from [ant.apache.org](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html):

```
  <ftp action="rmdir"
       server="${ftp.host}"
       userid="${ftp.user}"
       password="${ftp.pass}"
       remotedir="${ftp.parentdir_for_remotedir}" >
    <fileset>
      <include name="${ftp.remotedir}/**"/>
    </fileset>
  </ftp>
```

The quote from site:

> The directory specified in the remotedir parameter is never selected
>   for remove, so if you need to remove it, specify its parent in
>   remotedir parameter and include it in the  pattern, like
>   "somedir/**".

Also worth noting is that `rmdir` will fail if there are anything but empty folders in the `fileset` specified.

From the same site:

> As an example suppose you want to delete everything contained into
>   /somedir, so invoke first the  task with action="delete", then 
>   with action="rmdir" ...